# Display date based on condition of check box

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I am working within Infopath and I am trying display a today() or a now() in a field if a checkbox in the form is selected (ie auto populate a date if a checkbox is selected).

I tried making a rule "if checkbox is not blank, action, set field's value, today() 
but it doesnt work.

I was thinking of placing a IF statement 
(TrueResult | ElseResult) [(BoolCondition) + 1] but I have no idea how I would format that.

Thanks for your help/suggestions.

R

Answer (score 0):

Check the steps below.

1.Create a Infopath form.

2.Add Check Box control and a Text Box control into this form.

3.Click the Check Box, add rule->select "Is Checked"->"Set a Field's Value".
[image]

4.Set a field's value with today() method.
[image]